# Find a position vector where lines intersect

Tags: vectors

Points A and B have position vectors **a** and **b** with respect to an origin O.
Points P,Q and R are defined such that 3**OP** = **OA**, 3**OQ** = 2**OB**, 2**PR** = **RQ** and S is the point of intersection of AB and OR produced.

Find the position vector of R.

If AS = kAB and OS = l**OR** find the values of k and l.
Hence write the position vector of S.

I have drawn the attached diagram and have worked out that the position vector of R is:

$\frac{1}{3}$( $\frac{2}{3}$**a** + $\frac{1}{3}$**b**) =  $\frac{2}{9}$(**a** + **b**)

So S = $\frac{2l}{9}$(**a** + **b**)

But I can proceed no further.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using $AS = kAB$, we have:

$$\overrightarrow{OS}= \mathbf a + k \overrightarrow{AB} = \mathbf a + k (\mathbf b - \mathbf a) = (1-k)\mathbf a +k \mathbf b$$

You already got $\overrightarrow{OS} = \dfrac{2l}9 (\mathbf a + \mathbf b)$

Equate both and evaluate $k$, $l$.